# Access Active Directory Objects in SharePoint 2013 using c#

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, active-directory

I am trying to create a web-part which access the objects of active directory like "Users" "OU" etc. how can i access active directory to use this objects using c# code ?, i developing this web-part in SharePoint 2013.

Note : can i do this without LDAP?

can anybody know how to do this thing ?

Answer (score 1):

Considering the abundance of information to interface with AD I am surprised that you have not stumbled upon one of the following links:

- [Everything in Active Directory via C#.NET 3.5 (Using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/90142/Everything-in-Active-Directory-via-C-NET-3-5-Using)
- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)

These should get you started.